# Are there a way to insert into a SelectList at index without creating a new list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlist

Are there a way to insert a SelectListItem at the begining of a SelectList without creating a new list. Don't like the idea to iterate list if not nessary!

Edit: Need to clarify, MySelectList is of Object SelectList, Not List or Enumerate. (else it would be ez)

Something like: (This doesen't work)

```
SelectList MySelectList = new SelectList(SomeList, "Value", "Text");

MySelectList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Text = "", Value = "" });
```

Instead of:

```
SelectList MySelectList = new SelectList(SomeList, "Value", "Text");

MySelectList.ToList().Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Text = "", Value = "" });
MySelectedList = new SelectList(MySelectList, "Value", "Text");
```

Comment: Have you tried your first option? It will work. Read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4

Comment: Sorry, not that I asked for, but if it was a list it would have helped. I thought to my self that if I name it MySelectList ppl would know it's of Type SelectList. Sorry my mistake!